# Why don't we use & while reading strings in c using printf?

Tags: arrays, c, string

Today my professor started the topic of strings in C and he literally used scanf without attaching an ampersand to the variable that's being scanned for input.

I mean don't we need that & because it points to the variable in the memory? We always need & for other data types like int and float but why not for strings?

Here's a sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Your name is %s.", name);
    return 0;
}
```

My professor told me that we can use it without the ampersand for strings but why is it even valid?

Comment: Arrays are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements in many cases, including when passing them to functions (which is why some programmers confuse the two). It's as if you were passing `&name[0]`.

Comment: It's probably one of them "you'll understand when we get to the chapter about pointers" things. As in, just do as the teacher says for now and you'll understand why later on.